# How do I go about creating a dynamic QR code?

Tags: dynamic, qr-code

I scored a position working on a community project we are working on involving a walking trail. The vision is that we will have 4 different QR codes that are linked to playlists so that the community can share in a common experience. Walkers can scan any one of the four codes posted on trail markers to access these common play lists. Our group has a budget of $500 and we'll need badges to display on the walking trail by mid-May. How do I go about doing so? What program/software is most user-friendly?

Comment: You do not specify on what system or medium you wish to create these QR codes, or if it will be paper or screen. In any case, I personally find [Zint Barcode Creator](https://zint.github.io/) to be very flexible. It can run via command line and outputs many formats and symbologies.

Answer (score 0):

can you specifiy more about the term "Dynamic QR Code"?

For what I comprehens, The Printed QR Code (on the walking  is unchanged), but the link pointed to can be changed. is it something like that?

this is one image which help's describe about Dynamic QR Code - credit : [Binus University](https://socs.binus.ac.id/2018/12/15/pengenalan-qr-code/)
[image]

if it is so, you can use Link Shortener (e.g. BitLy), Social Media Lnding Page (e.g, Linktr.ee)  or Domain redirection.
.
Say you already generate 4 QR Code as follow

1. A.walktrail.xxx
2. B.walktrail.xxx
3. C.walktrail.xxx
4. D.walktrail.xxx

Then for each URL is set to point to specific playlist. Of course you can change it the content or the redirection later.

There a lot of QR Code Generator out there. So is the QR Code scanner. For generating QR Code, I usually use [NinjaQR](https://ninjaqr.com), since it is online and web based (user no need to install).